# Linear Transformation proof with odd notation, I want to make sure I understood properly

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

To start, I just want to let it be understood that scalars are denoted with Greek letters, and vectors with Latin letters.

Given a space, $V$, with an arbitrary basis $B_V = \{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$, and an arbitrary $W\subseteq V$ s.t. $W =\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$.Then there is a map $T$ s.t, $T: v_i \mapsto w_i$, and $T$ is a linear transformation.

This is the problem, and I wasn't quite sure how to interpret it. My understanding of it, and the way I did the proof was this; if $T: V \mapsto V_T$, where $V_T$ is the image of  T over $V$ then if $T$ is such that for any $x\in V$, if $x$  is a linear combination of the vectors in $B_V$,  $T(x)$ is a that linear combination with each $v_i$ replaced with $w_i$

For clarity, $x = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i \implies T(x) = T(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iw_i $

is how I understood the mapping.

Comment: If $W$ is a vector space with basis $\{w_i\}$, and $T$ takes a basis of $V$ to a basis of $W$, then $T$ is an isomorphism

Comment: @LukeTux, well in this case, W is only a subset of V, and not necessarily a basis (since it is possible it is linearly dependent).  But you answer kind of gives me the hint that the way I interpret the mapping was correct?

Comment: What are $\{w_i\}$ referring to?

Comment: "English letters" ... here, we call them "Latin letters".

Comment: $T$ is not, as written, fully defined. $T$ is only defined on the $v_i.$ Are you trying to show that there is one linear $T$ with this property?

Comment: As written, this is not true. In the real vector space, $\mathbb R^2$ with basis $v_1=(1,0),v_2=(0,1)$ we can take $W=\{(x,y)\mid y\geq 0\},$ $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_2$ and $T(x,y)=(x,y^2).$

Comment: @LukeTux the $\{w_i\}$ refer to the members of the subset of $W$ in the problem.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for letting me know, I will make the correction

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, not one unique mapping, but at least one. 

Let me ask a clarifying question before responding to you second comment. In your second you say "As written, this is not true." Do you mean to say it is not true that there is one unique linear transformation, or that there are any linear transformations at all with this property?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I edited the question so that hopefully it is more clear what I am asking.

Comment: The same map $T$ of @ThomasAndrews is a counterexample:
Take $V=\Bbb R^2$, $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(0,1)$, $w_1=v_1$, $w_2=v_2$, and define $T$ by the formula $T(x,y)=(x,y^2)$. Then $T \colon v_i \mapsto w_i$, but $T$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: The usual (correct) statement of this theorem is, "There exists a unique linear transformation $T$ such that $T(v_i) = w_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$."  In order to prove it, you must show that there is at most one such transformation (that's what your last formula does) and you must show that there exists such a transformation (which requires checking that the formula you've written down actually defines a linear transformation; if you don't explicitly use the fact that $B_V$ is a basis in this part, you haven't written the right proof.)

Comment: @azif00 I think between your comment, Andrews, and JBL I understand a bit more. The correct theorem is not that this is so for any transformation, but there is SOME transformation for which this is so. Is that accurate, or am I still missing the mark?

Comment: @JBL I think I used the fact that it was a basis. For $x,y\in V$, I started with the fact that $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i v_i$, and $y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i v_i$, so $x+y =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i v_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i + \beta_i) v_i   \implies T(x+y) = T(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i + \beta_i) v_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i + \beta_i) w_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i w_i = T(x)+T(y)$, and proceeded similarly for proving that the transformation preserved scalar multiplication

Comment: The set $W$ is unnecessary. I'd rewrite this as: "If $V$ is a vector space with basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and $w_1,\dots,w_n\in V,$ then there is a unique linear transformation $T:V\to V$ such that $Tv_i=w_i.$" The advantage of this is that the $w_i$ are not implied to be unique.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I guess it makes sense that referring to a set $W$ is unnecessary, I was just describing it as my textbook did. One quick question, does the notation $\{w_1,\ldots , w_n\}$ necessarily imply the uniqueness? I didn't think it did, since $\{a,a\} = \{a\}$, and in general, I thought it was the case that $\{ a,b\}=\{a\}=\{b\}$, so long as $a$ and $b$ have the same referent

Comment: Linear algebra textbooks tend to be rather vague about the differences between sets, multisets, and tuples.  Here $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is an ordered basis and $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is an ordered tuple of vectors (in particular, with duplication allowed).  

(Separately, usually the theorem is stated more generally, with the $w_i$ living in an arbitrary vector space over the same field as $V$.  The conclusion is the same.)